# Collapse historical rows by status in SQL using Group By

Tags: sql, oracle

i try to create a code snippet to use a context depending group by clause.

So what i have is something like 
Table1

```
Customer Status Date_FROM Date_TO
A        1      1.11.15   2.11.1
A        1      2.11.15   3.11.15
...      ...    ...       ...
A        2      5.11.15   6.11.15
...      ...    ...       ...
A        1      15.11.15  20.11.15
A        2      20.11.15  27.11.15
```

So i got customers with a changing Status and most time daily status rows. So in a simple scenario (just 2 intervals) i could use a code like:

```
    select Customer, Status, min(Date_FROM), max(Date_TO)
    from Table1 
    group by Customer, Status
```

But what i want in a more complex scenario is

Table2

```
Customer Status Date_FROM Date_TO
A        1      1.11.15   5.11.15
A        2      5.11.15   15.11.15
A        1      15.11.15  20.11.15
A        2      20.11.15  27.11.15
```

Is there some kind of analytical sql function that performs an aggregate as long as status (ordered by Date_FROM) doesn't change?

Greetings

Patrick

Comment: I were nice if you had an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) for this.

Comment: Not sure what precisely you are aiming at, but `lag` could be of interest ( matching record `n` with `n-1` on a given order allowing you to identify when a status change occurs ) as well as `listagg` which concatenates the values of a column over all rows in the resultset such that you can check whether the sequence of status values has changed.

Comment: Maybe you could use a subquery with `lag` that would be used to show "this is the row in which something changed", and then extract these rows with WHERE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would take some steps to do it and two analytic functions. Run it from inner step to the outer to understand what happens:

```
with a as(    
   select Customer, Status, Date_FROM, Date_TO,
       case when status <> lag(status) over (partition by customer order by date_from) 
       then 1 
       else 0 
       end status_switch
   from table),
b as(
select 
   Customer, 
   Status, 
   Date_FROM, 
   Date_TO, 
   sum(status_switch) over (partition by customer order by status_switch) as new_status_seq 
from a
)
select customer, status, min(date_from), max(date_to)
from b
group by customer, status, new_status_seq;
```

Not tested, there may be some errors, but you'll get the idea.

Comment: That looks interesting i think i understand enough to fix the errors (if exists). I will test it and share the results. Thanks

Comment: I have tested your statement and adapt it to my problem. It is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks a lot!